# fstab owner permissions

Tags: root, fstab, bind

I have set up line in fstab that goes like this:

```
/media/unas/raidstore /home/unas/raidstore none bind    0   0
```

It works a treat, except I can't set user privileges: they keep reverting to root, hence; access becomes an issue.

Here is the gparted

```
[sudo] password for unas: 
/dev/sda1: UUID="165728d7-4bff-41bb-ba76-9330e757a171" TYPE="ext2" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="OW1NDL-MyMl-2ATc-diPk-SMea-bWtN-uaatCX" TYPE="LVM2_member" 
/dev/sdc1: UUID="3087a575-39b2-2936-85dc-161b7c5c4898" UUID_SUB="4aaa380c-ae2d-3928-5aee-dcedbfc944e2" LABEL="UNAS:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member" 
/dev/sdb1: UUID="3087a575-39b2-2936-85dc-161b7c5c4898" UUID_SUB="ea4759dd-c45c-53a4-0401-f14faff8a7fc" LABEL="UNAS:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member" 
/dev/md0: LABEL="raidstore" UUID="cd690be0-7369-4d29-a40d-65c126b6a3e8" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: UUID="857397d8-c6e1-4023-81e4-1b494c0b5c6b" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: UUID="a5a718af-399a-4fbf-9ed7-b4a7f0b7c83f" TYPE="swap" 
======================
libparted : 2.3
======================

(gpartedbin:7903): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 7 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gpartedbin:7903): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 6 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gpartedbin:7903): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 26 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gpartedbin:7903): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 29 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gpartedbin:7903): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 28 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gpartedbin:7903): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 34 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gpartedbin:7903): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 33 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gpartedbin:7903): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 38 was not found when attempting to remove it

(gpartedbin:7903): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 37 was not found when attempting to remove it
Could not stat device --list - No such file or directory.
unas@UNAS:~$
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** Could you please go to a terminal by pressing [Ctrl][Alt][T] and type `sudo blkid&&sudo gparted --list`. Then [edit] your question and copy-paste the output of the command into your question so we can see what exact hardware you have. (Please help us help you!) Then leave a comment @Fabby.

Comment: am I replying in the correct area?                                                                                        when I paste it tells my I have too many characters ?

Comment: Click the small **[edit]** button below your original or click this orange **[edit]** link or any of the other orange **[edit]** links in my original comment...  **;-)**